# Open an empty page using WKWebViewRenderer if the uri is null in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using WKWebView Renderer for my App. In case if the url is not valid/ if the url is a string i would like to shown an empty webpage. How can I assign this in my renderer?

```
if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                HybridWebView hybridWebView = e.NewElement as HybridWebView;

                var uri = hybridWebView.Uri.ToString();

                if (uri.StartsWith("http") || uri.StartsWith("https"))
                {
                    LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(uri)));
                }
                else 
                {
                    LoadHtmlString($"{uri}", null);
                }

                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with follow code :

```
if (e.NewElement != null)
{
    HybridWebView hybridWebView = e.NewElement as HybridWebView;

    var uri = hybridWebView.Uri.ToString();

    if (uri.StartsWith("http") || uri.StartsWith("https"))
    {
         LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(uri)));
    }
    else 
    {
         string nullBodyHtml = "<html><body></body></html>";
         LoadHtml(nullBodyHtml, null);
    }

}
```

You can custom the `nullBofyHtml` to make the view shows a default effect when `uri` is null .

Such as : `string nullbodyString = "<html><body><h1>Xamarin.Forms invalid url</h1></body></html>";`

The effect as follow :

[image]